# Parsing Values Technique Required

Tags: php, parsing

i am working on admin panel to retrieve user DOB values on a page, i tried many times with different techniques but dint get quite well of it, just want to know what technique will be used to get thru, so please anyone could help in this case, i am providing all codes i am working on to make it easier for you, it would be highly appreciated.

HTML:
this is 
"add_user_profile.php"

```
<form action="add_user_profile_process.php" method="post">

<select name="day" id="day">

  <option value="">Day

  </option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
  <option value="8">8</option>
  <option value="9">9</option>
  <option value="10">10</option>
  <option value="11">11</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="13">13</option>
  <option value="14">14</option>
  <option value="15">15</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="17">17</option>
  <option value="18">18</option>
  <option value="19">19</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
  <option value="21">21</option>
  <option value="22">22</option>
  <option value="23">23</option>
  <option value="24">24</option>
  <option value="25">25</option>
  <option value="26">26</option>
  <option value="27">27</option>
  <option value="28">28</option>
  <option value="29">29</option>
  <option value="30">30</option>
  <option value="31">31</option>
</select>
<select name="month" id="month">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="Jan">Jan</option>
  <option value="Feb">Feb</option>
  <option value="Mar">Mar</option>
  <option value="Apr">Apr</option>
  <option value="May">May</option>
  <option value="Jun">Jun</option>
  <option value="Jul">Jul</option>
  <option value="Aug">Aug</option>
  <option value="Sep">Sep</option>
  <option value="Oct">Oct</option>
  <option value="Nov">Nov</option>
  <option value="Dec">Dec</option>
</select> 
<select name="year" id="year">
    <option value="">Year</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2011">2011</option>
  <option value="2010">2010</option>
  <option value="2009">2009</option>
  <option value="2008">2008</option>
  <option value="2007">2007</option>
  <option value="2006">2006</option>
  <option value="2005">2005</option>
  <option value="2004">2004</option>
  <option value="2003">2003</option>
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
  <option value="2001">2001</option>
  <option value="2000">2000</option>
  <option value="1999">1999</option>
  <option value="1998">1998</option>
  <option value="1997">1997</option>
  <option value="1996">1996</option>
  <option value="1995">1995</option>
  <option value="1994">1994</option>
  <option value="1993">1993</option>
  <option value="1992">1992</option>
  <option value="1991">1991</option>
  <option value="1990">1990</option>
  <option value="1989">1989</option>
  <option value="1988">1988</option>
  <option value="1987">1987</option>
  <option value="1986">1986</option>
  <option value="1985">1985</option>
  <option value="1984">1984</option>
  <option value="1983">1983</option>
  <option value="1982">1982</option>
  <option value="1981">1981</option>
  <option value="1980">1980</option>
  <option value="1979">1979</option>
  <option value="1978">1978</option>
  <option value="1977">1977</option>
  <option value="1976">1976</option>
  <option value="1975">1975</option>
  <option value="1974">1974</option>
  <option value="1973">1973</option>
  <option value="1972">1972</option>
  <option value="1971">1971</option>
  <option value="1970">1970</option>
  <option value="1969">1969</option>
  <option value="1968">1968</option>
  <option value="1967">1967</option>
  <option value="1965">1965</option>
  <option value="1964">1964</option>
  <option value="1963">1963</option>
  <option value="1962">1962</option>
  <option value="1961">1961</option>
  <option value="1960">1960</option>
</select>
</form>
```

PHP this is "add_user_profile_process.php"

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","php184_proj_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$dob_array = array();
if (isset($_POST['day']))
    $d[] = $_POST['day'];
if (isset($_POST['month']))
    $m[] = $_POST['month'];
if (isset($_POST['year']))
    $y[] = $_POST['year'];

$dob = implode('-', $dob_array);

$qry = "INSERT INTO users 
          (dob)
          VALUES 
          ('$dob')";

mysqli_query($con,$qry);

header("Location:user_list.php?success_msg=1");
?>
```

Now What i want to do is on "edit_user_profile.php" i want to parse values in select tags like this, so what should i use here to get values i mean to parse values from DB

```
<select>
      <option value="<?php echo $dob['0'];?>"><?php echo $dob['0'];?></option>
  <option value="1962">1962</option>
  <option value="1961">1961</option>
  <option value="1960">1960</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dob = array();
$sql= "SELECT dob FROM users";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $dob[] = $row['dob'];
}
```

And then inline with the HTML:

```
foreach($dob as $key => $val) {
    echo "<option value=\"$val\">$val</option>";
}
```